# Spring Bean Creation Help

Tags: spring

The requirement is that we have an interface and there are many implementation of it. Now, on the basis of the request input I need to pick the implementation, for example lets say there is a clientID parameter in request Object, and on the basis of clientID, I need to pick the implementation class.

```
<bean id = "clientService" class =" com.ecourt.CLientServiceImpl">
    <property name="someInterface" ref = "this needs to be changed for every client base on the request Input"/>
</bean>

<!-- Below mentioned Beans are Impl of "someInterface" property of above define bean --!>
<bean id ="clientOneImpl" class = "com.ecourt.clienOneImpl"/>
<bean id ="clientTwoImpl" class = "com.ecourt.clienTwoImpl"/>
```

The possible solution can be in SpEL expression, but till now, I managed to find out only this :

```
<property name="someInterface" ref="#{clientID =='101'?clientOneImpl:clientTwoImpl}"/>
```

But with this conditional statement I can handle utmost two clients. Is there any way to handle more than two clients? Is there any way to do this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can define beans with clientID as id attribute for each implementation. Call getBean() by passing clientID to return you the actual implementation based on given clientID.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your are building a Spring-based app, but this is a classic case of a Factory pattern. So, you could use that to achieve this, wherein you return the implementation corresponding to a given clientID (from your Factory).

Comment: +1 for factory: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions that comes from top of my mind.

1. One use java config to define the beans and then have switch case to return the appropriate bean.
2. Use named parameter of the bean to lookup for bean. i.e. in the switch map attribute to bean name, and then use context to lookup class by name.